# How to retrieve day from single column based on timestamp

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I  am inserting data daily into the database. I need to retrieve a single column data based on timestamp. I need to display today Usage and yesterday Usage based on the timestamp.

My actual table

```
name       usage          timestamp
prod        200     2019-01-08 09:22:53.364366
Test        100     2019-01-08 09:22:53.364366
qality      50      2019-01-08 09:22:53.364366
prod        270     2019-01-09 08:22:53.364366
Test        300     2019-01-09 08:22:53.364366
qality      90      2019-01-09 08:22:53.364366

Expecting output:

name       usage(yesterday)     usage(Today)         timestamp
prod        200                  270                2019-01-09 08:22:53.364366
Test        100                  300                2019-01-09 08:22:53.364366
qality      50                   90                 2019-01-09 08:22:53.364366
```

Answer (score 0):

Try aggregating by the name, and then check the timestamp:

```
SELECT
    name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN timestamp::date = NOW()::date - INTERVAL '1 DAY'
             THEN usage END) AS u_yesterday,
    MAX(CASE WHEN timestamp::date = NOW()::date
             THEN usage END) AS u_today,
    MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    name;
```